# Prove that $\mathcal{A}\preceq \mathcal{B}$.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, model-theory

Can someone check whether my solution is okay?

> If $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{B}$, $\mathcal{A}\preceq \mathcal{C}$, and $\mathcal{B}\preceq \mathcal{C}$, prove that $\mathcal{A}\preceq \mathcal{B}$.

Let $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, $\mathcal{A}\preceq \mathcal{C}$, and $\mathcal{B}\preceq \mathcal{C}$. Then for any $\mathcal{L}$-formulas $\phi$ and assignments $\alpha$, $\mathcal{A}\models \phi[\alpha]$ if and only if $\mathcal{C}\models \phi[\alpha]$ if and only if $\mathcal{B}\models \phi[\alpha]$. Then $\mathcal{A}\models \phi[\alpha]$ if and only if $\mathcal{B}\models \phi[\alpha]$ and by definition of substructures, $A\subseteq B$. Then $\mathcal{A}\preceq \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Can you define $\preceq, \mathcal L$-formula, assignment and $\models$?

Comment: @Jimmy That seems unreasonable; it would make the question too long. These are basic model-theoretic concepts.

Comment: Yes, the proof is fine.

Comment: The proof makes sense if $\preceq$ stands for "is an elementary substructure of". I think it would be reasonable to at least say explicitly _either_ that this is what $\preceq$ means here, _or_ to say explicitly which kinds of things the letters $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal C$ range over in the quoted goal.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see. Yes, it stands for elementary substructure, and $\mathcal{A,B,C}$ are just structures for a language! I am not sure about the range...

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Given a model theory tag, I don't think this needs to be explained, this is completely standard notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof seems okay. One point you glossed over a little bit more than you should have: when you choose $\alpha$, you should specify that it is an arbitrary assignment in $A$, and later on, when you use $B\preceq C$, you should deduce that it is therefore an assignment in $B$ (so you can apply $B\preceq C$). Just make sure you apply the hypothesis directly, and how you apply it. That should remove all doubt about correctness.